# Converting from JSON to XML

Tags: json, xml, go, struct, output

I have seen lots of posts on here about converting from XML to JSON, and I've recently wrote a program to do so, but I was also curious how you would go about converting from JSON to XML?

Sample JSON:

```
"version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Kearney, MO",
        "city":"Kearney",
        "state":"MO",
        "state_name":"Missouri",
```

I'm not sure if it'd be any use to you, but i'll post my JSON to XML program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "encoding/xml"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type reportType struct{
    Version xml.CharData        `xml:"version"`
    TermsOfService xml.CharData `xml:"termsofService"
    `
    Features xml.CharData       `xml:"features>feature"`
    Full     string     `xml:"current_observation>display_location>full"`
    StateName string        `xml:"current_observation>display_location>state_name"`
    WindGust string     `xml:"current_observation>observation_location>full"`
    Problem myErrorType     `xml:"error"`
}
type myErrorType struct{
    TypeOfError xml.CharData `xml:"type"`
    Desciption xml.CharData `xml:"description"`
}
type reportTypeJson struct{
    Version        string  `json:"version"`;
    TermsOfService string `json:"termsofService"`;
    Features    map[string]string `json:"features"`;
    CurrentObservation map[string]map[string]string `json:"current_observation"`

}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("data is from WeatherUnderground.")
    fmt.Println("https://www.wunderground.com/")
    var state, city string
    str1 := "What is your state?"
    str2 := "What is your city?"
    fmt.Println(str1)
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &state)
    fmt.Println(str2)
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &city)
    baseURL := "http://api.wunderground.com/api/";
    apiKey := "Nunna"
    var query string

    //set up the query
    query = baseURL+apiKey +
    "/conditions/q/"+
    url.QueryEscape(state)+ "/"+
    url.QueryEscape(city)+ ".xml"
    fmt.Println("The escaped query: "+query)

    response, err := http.Get(query)
    doErr(err, "After the GET")
    var body []byte
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    doErr(err, "After Readall")
    fmt.Println(body);
    fmt.Printf("The body: %s\n",body)

    //Unmarshalling
    var report reportType
    xml.Unmarshal(body, &report)
    fmt.Printf("The Report: %s\n", report)
    fmt.Printf("The description is [%s]\n",report.Problem.Desciption)

    //Now marshal the data out in JSON
    var data []byte
    var output reportTypeJson
    output.Version = string(report.Version);
    output.TermsOfService = string(report.TermsOfService)

    output.Features= map[string]string{"feature":string(report.Features)} // allocate a map, add the 'features' value to it and assign it to output.Features
    output.CurrentObservation = map[string]map[string]string {
        "display_location": map[string]string {
            "full": report.Full,
            "state_name": report.StateName,
        },"observation_location":map[string]string {"full": report.WindGust},
    }
    data,err = json.MarshalIndent(output,"","      ")
    doErr(err, "From marshalIndent")
    fmt.Printf("JSON output nicely formatted: \n%s\n",data)


}
func doErr( err error, message string){
    if err != nil{
        log.Panicf("ERROR: %s %s \n", message, err.Error())
    }


}
//OUTPUT:
//JSON output nicely formatted: 
//{
//     "version": "0.1",
//      "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
//      "features": {
//            "feature": "conditions"
//      },
//      "current_observation": {
//            "display_location": {
//                  "full": "Kearney, MO",
//                  "state_name": "Missouri"
//            },
//            "observation_location": {
//                  "full": "HOMESTEAD HILLS, Kearney, Missouri"
//            }
//      }
//}
```

Comment: It would be much more interesting to see the specification than the code. Converting JSON to some kind of XML is trivial; the challenge is designing a conversion that is capable of handling edge cases (e.g. JSON containing characters that aren't valid in XML) without producing unusable results in "ordinary" cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same process as going in the other direction. Define structs/objects to model the input (be it json in this case), create method to assign all the values from the struct modeling the input to the one you're using for output, then marshal the output to get a string. So to give a practice example using one of the more conceptually difficult fields from you type, having unmarshalled some json into an instance of `reportTypeJson` I can assign to `reportType` used to model xml like so;

```
report.StateName = jsonReport.CurrentObservation["display_location"]["state_name"]
```

The biggest difference here is the struct representing your xml is flat (like it has Something>InnerSomething>InnerInnerSomething to represent it's nested values while the struct in golang has no nesting) where as with the json, your structures in golang tend to have the same amount of nesting (like having a map[string]map[string][string] meaning items are nested 3 levels inside of the main struct). You can observe this by the amount of indirection when you access fields, like in the example above, there is one level of indirection to access `CurrentObservation` but that is a map of maps, so then I index into it with the `display_location` key which yields a `map[string]string`, since I'm looking for the statename value, I have to index into that with `state_name` to access that value.

Note that in an actual program, a number of checks would be required because these operations are unsafe. For example, if the json read did not contain a `display_location` object then `jsonReport.CurrentObservation["display_location"]` would return `nil` and the attempt to access `["state_name"` would result in a panic.

Also, another side note, in your program I would recommend adding two functions, one called `NewJsonReport(report *reportType) *reportTypeJson, err` and one called `NewXmlReport(report *reportTypeJson) *reportType, err` in which you initialize/allocate the a new instance of the return type and return it as to avoid code duplication and make your programs `main` more readable. Doing this type of assignment in more than one location in a program is sloppy coding which will add a lot of maintenance cost and is likely to result in bugs down the line (like if something changes on one of the models or the input you have to fix every reference to it throughout the program rather than just updating the functions I mentioned above).